# Rudin Definition of Derivative 5.1

Tags: calculus, analysis

On the real number metric space, there is a function f defined on interval [a,b].  For any $x \in [a,b]$, there is a function:
$$\phi(t) = \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\qquad(a<t<b, t \neq x)$$

Then define the derivative ${f'}$ as:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{t\to x}\phi(t)$$

The question I cannot seem to figure out is why the restriction of $a<t<b$ on $\phi(t)$?  Function seems well defined except when denominator is zero.  When taking limits, it seems redundant when evaluating x at the endpoints by $t\neq x$.  For interior x, starting at the endpoints is inconsequential since we are moving towards x.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If $t \notin [a,b]$, then it will be outside the domain of $f$, so you cannot define $\phi$ there.

For $t = a$ or $t = b$, there is no particular reason to bother defining $\phi$ at these points, since the whole purpose of $\phi$ is in taking the limit. For $x \in (a,b)$, that limit is defined entirely by the behavior of $\phi$ away from $t = a, t = b$. And for for $x = a$ or $x = b$, the limit definition specifically avoids evaluating $t$ at that point.

So in no case is there a need for $\phi$ to have a value at $t = a, t = b$, and the author simply didn't bother to include them.

Comment: The function is naturally defined at the endpoints because f is defined at the endpoints. 
 Usually we put constraints because of harmful behavior (such as divide by zero) not vacuous behavior so that is why I may be overthinking this.  It seems like we are both in agreement that it is benign to have the function defined at the endpoints.  And in my opinion it is an oddity to include the constraint.  I can always start a proof with a vacuous truth, if X and the sky is blue then...

Comment: The constraint is necessary. $\phi$ is not definable for general $t$. It just could have allowed $t = a, t = b$, but did not need to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you clarify what you mean by "...for $x\in (a,b)$, that limit is defined entirely by the behaviour of $\phi$ away from $t=a, t=b$."? When $x\in (a,b)$, we have $0<|t-x|<\delta$ for some small $\delta$, however, $t$ could very well be $a$ or $b$ here, no?

Comment: @sunny - No, indeed. When $\delta$ becomes small enough, neither $t = a$ nor $t = b$ will satisfy $0< |t - x| < \delta$. And while there are some functions $f$ such that a fixed value of $\delta$ will work for any $\epsilon$, no matter how small, it is generally the case that $\delta$ must decrease towards $0$ as $\epsilon$ does. And even when such a fixed $\delta$ is possible, it is never required.